# get number of each day of week between two dates

Tags: php, date

I need to get the number of days for each day of the week between two dates like:

```
2013-01-01 to 2013-01-15

Mo:2
Tu:3
We:2
Th:2
Fr:2
Sa:2
Su:2
```

I had this code not sure where I got it before but it seemed to be working but realized theres some date ranges it does not work on like 2013-03-01 to 2013-03-11 it reports Monday as 1 day instead of 2 days.

```
function daysOfWeekBetween($start_date, $end_date, $weekDay)
{
   $first_date = strtotime($start_date." -1 days");
   $first_date = strtotime(date("M d Y",$first_date)." next ".$weekDay);

   $last_date = strtotime($end_date." +1 days");
   $last_date = strtotime(date("M d Y",$last_date)." last ".$weekDay);

   return  floor(($last_date - $first_date)/(7*86400)) + 1;
}

daysOfWeekBetween($date_range['start_date'], $date_range['end_date'], 'Monday');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) manual. The very first exemple does exactly what you need.

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

function count_weekdays_between($start, $end) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/', $start, $start) && preg_match('/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/', $end, $end)) {
        $start  = mktime(0, 0, 0, $start[2], $start[3], $start[1]);
        $end    = mktime(0, 0, 0,   $end[2],   $end[3],   $end[1]);
        $offset = date('w', $start);
        $delta  = ($end - $start) / 86400;

        $result = array_fill(0, 7, floor($delta / 7));

        for ($i = 0; $i <= ($delta % 7); ++$i) {
            $result[$offset]++;
            $offset = ($offset + 1) % 7;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That only tells me what one date is. Is there no mathematical way to figure it out without having to loop through every date between two days and figuring out on a day by day basis which day the date is?

Comment: That did not work: using 2013-03-01 - 2013-03-11 I get this: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 )` When I should get `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 ) ` Which is exactly what my original script did with that date range (Monday is off).

Comment: Here the period 2013-03-01 - 2013-03-11 worked just fine. Try setting this to your script: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution:

```
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $begin = new DateTime($date_range['start_date']);
    $end = new DateTime($date_range['end_date']);
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    foreach($period as $dt)
    {
        $inner_data['average_days_counter'][$dt->format('D')] = isset($inner_data['average_days_counter'][$dt->format('D')]) ? $inner_data['average_days_counter'][$dt->format('D')] + 1 : 1;
    }
    // Array ( [Mon] => 2 [Tue] => 1 [Wed] => 1 [Thu] => 1 [Fri] => 2 [Sat] => 2 [Sun] => 2 )
```

Comment: I thought you wanted a solution "without having to loop through every date between two days"

Comment: @Havenard I did but couldn't find one so this is what I will use unless someone else has a better solution.

Comment: I just gave you a better solution.